# NFS mount hangs reboot

Tags: linux, nfs

I have a couple of NFS mounts I am auto-mounting in fstab. Everything is fine till reboot then it hangs trying to unmount them, but I can manually umount them manually before reboot without issue. The server is still online and accessible when this happens. If it makes any difference, the workstation is Debian 8, and the server is Centos6.

//fstab //

> devbox:/coding/go /nfs-mounts/go  nfs auto 0 0
>
> devbox:/usr/share/nginx/html/thriftstore

/nfs-mounts/thriftstore nfs auto 0 0

//hosts//

> 192.168.0.190 devbox.localdomain  devbox

Answer (score 0):

I have the same bug, i made a dirty workaround. I put a line in `/etc/init.d/sendsigs`:

```
do_stop () {
        invoke-rc.d umountnfs stop    # this is the new line
        OMITPIDS=
```

Answer (score 0):

`sudo umount -lf /mount_point` is sufficient to fix things.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue when NFS was down.

I've set the `bg`,`timeo=100` and `retry=0` so the OS fails to mount, it won't try again and boot once the timeout is reached.

```
Edit /etc/fstab to be:
RemoteServer:/My/local/path  
/My/local/path nfs auto,defaults,soft,int,tcp,bg,timeo=100,retry=0 0 0
```